why can't I package my local dependency (json-20210307.jar) into my project jar using maven shade plugin?
my maven project needs some local dependencies and i put them in the lib directory, my project structure is as follows(test_local_jar is my project name)
test_local_jar ->lib ->json-20210307.jar
                          -\>commons-codec-1.10.jar  ...                                                      

                 -\>src...-\>org.example-\>Main -\>target -\>pom.xml 

I tried to package my maven project using maven shade plugin (i also want to learn about some common maven package plugins ) and i hope to use the project.jar in another PC without installing the jdk, dependencies and so on. I can include other dependencies into my project by typing mvn clean package in the terminal, but i can't include json-20210307.jar(other versions can't be included, either). Error message is as follows: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:9) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ...
my pom.xml is as follows, where i use maven shade plugin and set the mainClass, location of my dependencies and so on. All dependencies in my project are local dependencies. i want to find out the way to include json-20210307.jar(or other version) into my jar and understand why i can't include json.jar into my project jar. In fact, i dont know the meaning of memu structure **/*.jar, i dont know what's the ** meaning. Besides, i want to learn more about some other maven package plugins which can be used to package dependencies.
<dependencies> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>test_local_jar</groupId> 
<artifactId>commons-codec-1.10</artifactId> 
<version>1.10</version>
 <scope>system</scope> 
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar</systemPath> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>test_local_jar</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId> 
<version>4.4.1</version> 
<scope>system</scope> 
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpclient-4.4.1.jar</systemPath> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>test_local_jar</groupId> 
<artifactId>httpcore</artifactId> 
<version>4.4.1</version> 
<scope>system</scope> 
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar</systemPath> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>test_local_jar</groupId> 
<artifactId>json</artifactId> 
<version>20210307</version> 
<scope>system</scope> 
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/json-20210307.jar</systemPath> 
</dependency> 
</dependencies> 
<build> 
<plugins> 
<plugin> 
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>3.2.4</version> 
<executions> 
<execution> <!-- <id>make-assembly</id>--> 
<phase>package</phase> 
<goals> <goal>shade</goal> 
</goals> 
</execution> 
</executions> 
<configuration> 
<transformers> 
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"> <manifestEntries> 
<Main-Class> org.example.Main </Main-Class> 
</manifestEntries> 
</transformer> 
</transformers>
 <finalName>test-jar-with-dependencies</finalName> 
</configuration> 
</plugin> 
</plugins> 
<resources> 
<resource> 
<targetPath>lib/</targetPath> 
<directory>lib/</directory> 
<includes> <include>**/*.jar</include> 
</includes> 
</resource> 
</resources> 
</build>

my jar structure is as follows, i can find the json.jar in the lib directory, however, when i use java -jar .....jar in the cmd, error message appears(see details of my problems)
test-jar-with-dependencies.jar ->lib ->...other jars
                                                      -\>json-20210307.jar                                                                                                                                                -\>META-INF                                                                                                                                                                     -\>org-\>example-\>Main.class


to get started, why on earth commons-codec as a system dependency?

Have you read the documentation of Maven and the plugins?

@GyroGearless My another project needs it, so i just keep the settings, anyway, commons-codec seems to have nothing to do with my problem...

@aled not yet... i just find the maven settings using search engines to save time and the solution is very confusing...i dont know how much time i have to learn thoroughly about the maven plugin by maven documents.

Please [ask] to understand how make questions in [so].

Do not use system scoped dependencies.. Use regular ones... If you like to create an executable jar yes maven-shade-plugin is the right way to go... check this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/jacem/blob/main/cralinkr/cli/pom.xml
